# Get video duration with mediaelementjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mediaelement.js

I'm using mediaelementjs library for a project.

**HTML**

```
<video width="640" height="360" id="player1" preload="none">
    <source type="video/youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI" />
</video>
```

**Javascript / jQuery**

```
$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({

    loop: false,
    features: ['playpause','progress','volume'],
    success: function(player, node) {

        $('#' + node.id + '-mode').html('mode: ' + player.pluginType);
        console.log(player.duration);    
    }
});
```

but `console.log(player.duration)` return always 0
So i think that maybe something wrong.

How can i get the video duration(in seconds) of video with mediaelementjs library?

Help me please.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably getting this because metadata of the media element is not yet loaded, checking after adding a event listener to that should solve the problem:

```
success: function(player, node) {

    $('#' + node.id + '-mode').html('mode: ' + player.pluginType);
    player.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(){
        console.log(player.duration);    
    });

}
```